# Exception while using Apache Commons Mail API from IBM Worklight Studio 5.0.5

Tags: apache, email, jakarta-mail, ibm-mobilefirst

I have been trying to make use of Apache Commons API with in a Java class to send out an email. I invoke this Java function from a worklight adapter in order to send the email.

I'm making use of Worklight Studio on a Mac, version of the studio is: 5.0.5.20131003

Here is the piece of Java Code:

```
package com.customclass.helper;
import org.apache.commons.mail.HtmlEmail; 

public class EmailHelper{

public static void sendHTMLMail (String serverHostName, String serverPort, String isSSLEnabledOnServer, String isTLSEnabledOnServer, String fromAddress, String toAddress, String cc, String bcc, String subject, String body){


HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
email.setHostName(serverHostName);
email.setSmtpPort(serverPort);
email.setSSLOnConnect(isSSLEnabledOnServer);
email.setStartTLSEnabled(isTLSEnabledOnServer);
email.addTo(toAddressArray);
email.addCc(ccArray);
email.addBcc(bcc);
email.setSubject(subject);
email.setMsg(body);
email.send();}}
```

This is how in invoke it from the Adapter:

```
com.customclass.helper.EmailHelper.sendHTMLMail(SMTP_SERVER_HOST, SMTP_SERVER_PORT, SMTP_SERVER_SSL_ENABLED, SMTP_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED, fromMailAddress, toAddress, cc, bcc, subject, body);
```

The SMTP server that I'm making use of does not require any authentication and does not work on SSL or TLS and are set to false.

When I run the Java class as a stand alone Java application it works fine, but when its utilised from with in the Worklight server using the adapter it throws an exception. The exception does not have enough information in it for me to debug the issue.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Exception while sending email:Sending the email to the following server failed : my.smtp.server.com:25
                              com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:676)
                              javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:189)
                              javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
                              org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
                              org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
                              com.customclass.helper.EmailHelper.sendHTMLMail(EmailHelper.java:131)
                              sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                              sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
                              sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
                              java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
                              org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:161)
                              org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:247)
                              org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:86)
                              org.mozilla.javascript.gen._2FUsers_2F914854_2Fprojects_2Fcustom_2Fworkspaces_2Fphase2dec10_2FMyWorklightProject_2Fadapters_2FMessageAdapter_MessageAdapter_impl_js_593._c_sendEmail_1(%2FUsers%2F914854%2Fprojects%2Fcustom%2Fworkspaces%2Fphase2dec10%2FMyWorklightProject%2Fadapters%2FMessageAdapter/MessageAdapter-impl.js:91)
                              org.mozilla.javascript.gen._2FUsers_2F914854_2Fprojects_2Fcustom_2Fworkspaces_2Fphase2dec10_2FMyWorklightProject_2Fadapters_2FMessageAdapter_MessageAdapter_impl_js_593.call(%2FUsers%2F914854%2Fprojects%2Fcustom%2Fworkspaces%2Fphase2dec10%2FMyWorklightProject%2Fadapters%2FMessageAdapter/MessageAdapter-impl.js)
                              org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:426)
                              org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3178)
                              org.mozilla.javascript.gen._2FUsers_2F914854_2Fprojects_2Fcustom_2Fworkspaces_2Fphase2dec10_2FMyWorklightProject_2Fadapters_2FMessageAdapter_MessageAdapter_impl_js_593.call(%2FUsers%2F914854%2Fprojects%2Fcustom%2Fworkspaces%2Fphase2dec10%2FMyWorklightProject%2Fadapters%2FMessageAdapter/MessageAdapter-impl.js)
                              com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.callFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:180)
                              com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptManager.invokeFunction(JavaScriptManager.java:156)
                              com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl.invokeFunction(AdapterManagerImpl.java:101)
                              com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.invoke(JavaScriptProcedureInvoker.java:42)
                              com.worklight.integration.model.ProcedureInvoker.invokeProcedure(ProcedureInvoker.java:57)
                              com.worklight.integration.model.Procedure.invoke(Procedure.java:165)
                              com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:150)
                              com.worklight.integration.model.InvocationContext.call(InvocationContext.java:34)
                              java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
                              java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
                              java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
                              java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
                              java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Is there some thing that I'm missing to do on the Worklight studios embedded Jetty server?

Comment: I had asked this question previously but unfortunately since it was not updated in the past one month the system had deleted it, hence re creating the question again

Comment: This is not an exact solution to the problem but the way in which I had got around this issue is to make use of Java's Mail API instead of Apache's mail API. Looks like some of the JARs/Java Classes that Apache is dependant on does not seem to work well with the Worklight server both the embedded server with the IDE and also the server deployed on WAS

Comment: I suggest to write this workaround as an answer in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had got around this issue by making use of Java's Mail API instead of Apache's mail API. Looks like some of the JARs/Java Classes that Apache is dependant on does not seem to work well with the Worklight server both the embedded server with the IDE and also the server deployed on WAS